# Entity Framework deletion issue

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I've got a simple application which has 2 tables (tblGrade and tblWidth). Grade can have multiple Widths. I set this up in sqlserver to have cascaded deletes and I also set cascade delete on the relationship in the edmx file. The foreign key is non nullable.

I've bound a datagridview to the Widths collection. This works fine, allowing me to add, view and delete the records however when I come to save the changes i get the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I've done some looking around and virtually everything points to me having to explicitly delete the Width entity.

1. If the relationship is set to cascade deletes why do I have to explicitly delete this record?
2. Can i fix this without my form having to have a reference to the context. I was thinking of handling the SavingChanges event to remove the orphaned Width records but I'm not sure how to do that. (My app actually has a much more nested structure but I've cut it down for the example and I don't fancy passing the context to each of the controls or bubbling up delete events).

Any ideas / things to look at would be most appreciated as I'm pretty new to EntityFramework.

```
        Using ctxt As New ProductionDataEntities
            Dim grade = ctxt.Grades.First()
            Dim width = grade.GradeWidths(0)
            grade.GradeWidths.Remove(width)
            'ctxt.DeleteObject(width) **** will pass if this is uncommented.
            ctxt.SaveChanges()
        End Using
```

*Details: EF5 - Db First, SqlServer 2012, vb.net 2010*

Comment: grade.GradeWidths.Remove(width) means: remove width from grade's navigation property, so set the FK from width to grade to NULL... which it can't do, since the FK is not nullable. Cascade delete will not work here, since nothing is actually deleted... just the FK's are modified by EF. The only possibility would be to actually delete the widths - which would actually not result in an additional DB call compared to your current one.

Comment: Thanks @DevilSuichiro great explanation of what is happening. It pointed the way for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution which does what I was after. I use the SavingChanges event to detect if there is no parent for the child entity and then I call delete. This way my code is free just to consume the entities without needing a reference to the context.

```
Partial Public Class ProductionDataEntities

    Private Sub OnSavingChanges(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SavingChanges
        For Each entry As ObjectStateEntry In ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified)
            Dim gradeWidth = TryCast(entry.Entity, GradeWidth)
            If gradeWidth IsNot Nothing Then
                If gradeWidth.Grade Is Nothing Then
                    Me.DeleteObject(gradeWidth)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Thanks to everyone for the help.